# Filter all visible lists with inputs in form jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am developing form.

What I need is when a user tries to go to another page with empty VISIBLE fields/checkboxes/radios these fields/checkboxes/radios should become red.

Filters for checkboxes: min 1, max 5.

My jQuery

```
const max = 5;
const min = 1;
const minCheckedCheckboxes = 1;

$('input.checkbox').on('click', function(evt) {
  const checkboxes = $(this).closest('.cd-form-list-inner').find('input:checked');

  if(checkboxes.length > max) {
    alert('You can select only 5 checkboxes');
    return false;
  }
});

$('.next').click(function() {
    let error = false;
    $(['input[required]:visible', 'textarea[required]:visible']).each(function(index, selector) {                
        $(selector).each(function(index, input) {
            error = error == true ? error : $(input).val() == '';
        });
    });

    $('.parent:visible').each(function(index, group){
        if(error == true) {
            error = error;
        }
        else {
            error = $('input:checked', group).length < minCheckedCheckboxes;                
        }
    });


    if(error == false) {
        error =! $('input[type=radio]:required').is(':checked');
    }


    if(error) {
        $('input[required]:visible, textarea[required]:visible').removeClass("error");
        $('input[required]:visible, textarea[required]:visible').filter(function() {
            return !this.value;
        }).addClass('error');
        return alert('Not all required fields are filled');
        }
    alert('All required fields are filled');
});
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f50a5ymn/27/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if below code works for you!

1. Looped on all desired inputs.
2. Checked the input type while looping, accordingly created the condition to add the error class, also maintained the `elem` on which `error` class needs to be added.
3. Then if `condition` is true then added `error` class to `elem`.

```js
const max = 5;
const min = 1;

$('.next').click(function() {


  $('input[required]:visible,textarea[required]:visible,input[type="checkbox"]:visible').each(function(index, selector) {

    var elem;
    if ($(this).is(":checkbox") || $(this).is(":radio")) {

      var pDiv = $(this).parents("div").first();
      var condition = false;
      elem = pDiv;
      if ($(this).is(":radio")) {
        condition = pDiv.find("[type='radio']:checked").length <= 0
      } else {

        condition = pDiv.find("[type='checkbox']:checked").length < min || pDiv.find("[type='checkbox']:checked").length > max;
      }

    } else {
      condition = !$(this).val();
      elem = $(this);
    }

    if (condition) {
      elem.addClass('error');
    } else {
      elem.removeClass('error');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  background-color: pink;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p>press button</p>
<input type="text" required/>
<input type="text" required style="display: none" />
<div>
  <textarea cols="5" required placeholder="textarea"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
  <textarea cols="5" required placeholder="textarea" style="display:none"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <p>this div should be red</p>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" required>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent" display: none>
  <p>this div shouldn't be red</p>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" checked required>
  </div>
</div>
<div style="display:none">
  <p>this div shouldn't be red</p>
  <input type="radio" required>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <p>this div shouldn't be red</p>
  <div class="cd-form-list-inner checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent" style="display: none;">
  <p>this div shouldn't be red</p>
  <div class="cd-form-list-inner checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <p>this div should be red</p>
  <div class="cd-form-list-inner checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="next">Next page</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah! Thank you a lot!